# Mongodb on solaris10 64bit - I'm getting 'Invalid argument' when trying to run ./mongod

Tags: mongodb, solaris-10

I've unzipped and detarred the solaris install package from the mongo site - version 1.6.3.  When I try to run the ./mongod command I get the following (running as root):

$ ./mongod

bash: ./mongod: Invalid argument

Same thing happens for the rest of the executables.  I've created the data folder as per the instructions, but I'm probably missing something basic.  I've also chmod'd and chown'd the entire directory, but no luck.

Thoughts?

Comment: Did you have any luck? I am also having similar problem when I install the mongodb on solaris. >bash-2.05$ bin/mongod --help
>bash: bin/mongod: cannot execute binary file

Comment: Nope - I ended up using mysql, which is working great.  It does carry more baggage than mongodb, but it's something that most people know - therefore easier to hand off.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be how the Solaris SPARC big-endian problem manifests itself?  I am running into same problem and other web searching makes me think Mongo isn't compatible w/ Solaris SPARC machines.  If this impacts you please vote for fix.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1625

Comment: Yes, this can be confirmed to be Solaris SPARC issue

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should not need to run mongo as root. I would try to explicitly define both the `--dbpath` and the `--logpath`. See if that doesn't at least give you a log file with more details of the crash?

Comment: Tried the following as root:  $  ./mongod --dbpath /apps/mongodb-sunos5-x86_64-1.6.3/data/db/ --logpath /apps/mongodb-sunos5-x86_64-1.6.3/log   same result:   bash: ./mongod: Invalid argument       (also tried it as myself - no dice)

Comment: Add to say it, but I would check the mailing groups: http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user

Comment: May just be a case of a bad build or failed dependency loading. I don't know that many of the devs are really testing on Solaris, so it's worth double-checking the groups that nothing is funny.

Comment: I have a feeling that it has to do with allowed memory for some reason (oracle instances on Solaris 10 run into similiar issues).  Looking into that now.  Thanks for the references to the groups.